# Connect external Javascript with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to get on-click coordinates of the screen. I have written a very basic code for the same. I am not able to connect my external js file with Flask.

When I run the .html file the code works perfectly fine. When I connect it through Flask, I tried including the Javascript in the HTML code itself and even that works. But when the Javascript part is connected via a .js file, the part in the .js file doesn't work.
I don't see any errors so it is getting difficult to debug.

**Python script:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/button_click')
def button_click():
    return render_template('button_click.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
    <head><title> Button Click </title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="example">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='button_click.js') }}"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
function printMousePos(event) {
    document.body.textContent =
    "clientX: " + event.clientX +
    " - clientY: " + event.clientY;
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

```
Expected Result:
clientX: 93 - clientY: 113

Actual Result:
No change on screen
```

Comment: Your code works as expected in my environment(Latest Arch Linux + Google Chrome). Check browser's developer tool and see what's happening.

Comment: works too `windows`, `python3.6`, make sure that you put the static file in right place.

Comment: <html>
    <head><title> Button Click </title></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='button_click.js') }}"> </script>
        <div id="example">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

I just made this small change. I moved the script tag above the div tag and the code worked. Why so?

Comment: can  you reproduce the problem to change it back

Comment: Check your browser developer console, you might find some error. BTW, when adding listener, you should make sure the whole page is rendered: put those code in `onload`.

Comment: I don't know whether it makes difference, but changing whole the `document.body.textContent` is bit strange since the body contains `<script ...>` tag. maybe you should put the script outside of the body.